# console.log arbitrary number of arguments inline

Tags: javascript

Suppose we have a `function(a, b, c, d, e...){console.log(a,b,c,d,e)}`

This will console.log **inline** the variables `a,b,c,d,e` but if the function were to have argument `f` passed to it (or more arguments) it would not be logged.

The following will log everything:

`console.log(arguments)` but it is displayed as a Arguments[] object.

I have also tried:

```
for (let i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        console.log(arguments[i]);
    }
```

Which will log every argument but **each on a new line**. Is it possible to `console.log` all arguments **inline** when the number of arguments is arbitrary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spread the `arguments` into the `console.log` call:

```
function(a, b, c, d, e){
  console.log(...arguments);
}
```

Or, use rest parameters

```
function(...args){
  console.log(...args);
}
```